# How to access firebird database read-only (command-line)

Tags: firebird, isql

I have to use firebird with one of application. I want to access this database outside, using linux command-line scripts such fbexport or isql-fb. And It works perectly unless the main application is running.

```
Checking database charset...ERROR!
*** IBPP::SQLException ***
Context: Database::Connect
Message: isc_attach_database failed

SQL Message : -551
This user does not have privilege to perform this operation on this object.

Engine Code    : 335544352
Engine Message :
no permission for read-write access to database XYZ.FDB
```

I don't need write access, i want only do some selects, but i can't find the option to connect read-only to database. Is it possible with fbexport/isql-fb or maybe is there any other program?

Comment: Is your application using Firebird embedded?  If so, [an exclusive lock is put on the file prohibiting access from other applications](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/ufb-cs-embedded.html).  You'll need to run full blown Firebird server if two processes need to access the database at the same time.  Even connections not making changes need write access to increment the transaction counter, etc.

Comment: Does the application use Firebird embedded or Firebird server (and if so: Classic, SuperClassic or SuperServer)?

Comment: The original application use Firebird 2.5.3.26778 Firebird 2.5. And now i think that the problem is that I try to use two servers using the same file...